# Почему мне выводит ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' которая возникает при попытке перевода текста в googletrans

Tags: python

код:

```
import tkinter as tk
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
window = tk.Tk()

window.title('Translate')
window.geometry('600x400+400+150')

Label = tk.Label(text='Test')
Label.pack()

Text_lan = tk.Text(height=1, width=5)
Text_lan.pack()


Text_translate = tk.Text(height=3, width=20)
Text_translate.place(y=100, x=50)


def translate():
    tr = translator.translate(str(Text_translate), dest='ru')
    Text_translate.insert(tk.END, f'\n{str(tr)}')


window.btn = tk.Button(text='Translate', command=translate)
window.btn.place(y=100, x=250)


window.mainloop()
```

ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/366

Comment: А вы смотрели, что получается то у вас тут: `str(Text_translate)`? Может у `Text_translate` всё-таки есть какое-то поле, из которого можно достать текст, который там лежит?

Comment: Коротко - str(Text_translate) не получает текст из виджета, а дает текстовое представления класса. Как получить текст из виджета Text см. в вопросе, указанном в причине закрытия.